# JQUERY AJAX :lt(2) not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

IE Trouble...again.

This code works fine in all browsers including IE8:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false  
    });  
   var ajax_load = "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";  
   var loadUrl = "http://DOMAIN.co.uk/investor/news_table.php .newspost:lt(2)";  
   $(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#homenews").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);  
   });
```

Removing the  .newspost:lt(2) works. But I need to filter the content to only show only the first two .newspost spans.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: What version of IE does this not work in? IE 7?

Comment: It might be easier to customize it, so that you actually set up an AJAX call, then on success, look through the response for the `.newspost:lt(2)` and only append those to the target container.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. How can I go about doing this? IE 7,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be brief, customizing an AJAX call instead of using `load` might be a better solution for you:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});

var ajax_load = "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";
$("#homenews").html(ajax_load);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://DOMAIN.co.uk/investor/news_table.php",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#homenews").html($(data).find(".newspost:lt(2)"));
    }
});
```

I'm pretty sure this is basically what `load` does, it' just a wrapper for an `$.ajax` call.

You might have to set up some more options for the `$.ajax` call though.

Comment: Ahhhhh thats closer...It works when .newspost is a span. However..it is now a td <td align="left" valign="top" class="newspost">. Changing this to td.span:lt(2) isnt working...

Comment: I just created divs for all the news entries. So all working now! Thank you!